# bash gnu parallel argfile syntax

Tags: gnu-parallel

I just discovered GNU parallel and I'm having some trouble running a simple parallel task.  I have a simulation running over multiple values and I'd like to split it up to run in parallel using command line args.  From the [docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html) , it seems you can run `parallel mycommand :::: myargfile` in which `myargfile` contains the various arguments you would like to feed your command, in parallel.  However, I didn't see any information on how the args should be listed and assumed a `myargfile` like this would work:

```
--pmin 0 --pmax 0.1
--pmin 0.1 --pmax 0.2
...
```

`mycommand --pmin 0 --pmax 0.1` executes no problem.  But when I run `parallel mycommand :::: myargfile` I get `error: unknown option pmin 0 --pmax 0.1` (caught and decoded courtesy boost program options).  `parallel echo :::: myargfile` correctly prints out the arguments.  It's as if they are being wrapped in a string which the program can't read and not fed like they are from a standard bash script.

What's going on?  How can I make this work?

Comment: This question might have been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6258206/1328439).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @DmitriChubarov's link to https://stackoverflow.com/a/6258206/1328439 , I discovered that I was lacking the `colsep` flag:

```
parallel --colsep ' ' mycommand :::: myargfile
```

successfully executes.

Answer (score 0):

After digging through manual and help pages I came up with this example. Perhaps it will save someone out there. :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

COMMANDS=(
  "cnn -a mode=flat"
  "cnn -a mode=xxx"
  "cnn_x -a mode=extreme"
)

parallel --verbose --progress --colsep ' ' scrapy crawl {.} ::: "${COMMANDS[@]}"
```